# Appcelerator iTunes Sync is dead. How do I share iOS app builds now?

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, appcelerator, itunes

Apple just pushed out a new iTunes update (12.7) that removed "apps" from iTunes. Now I'm unsure how to send files to people for testing. Previously I would:

1. Add the target's UUID to my development cert
2. Select "MyAppName" in project explorer
3. Run -> iOS Device -> iTunes Sync
4. Find "MyAppName.ipa" @ "Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications/MyAppName.ipa"
5. Copy MyAppName.ipa into Dropbox

My testers could then download from the dropbox, install, and test on their device. That process no longer works as of this iTunes 12.7 update. So how do I share test builds now? I'm desperate here. Thanks!

Comment: You should really look into using Apple's Test Flight.  For internal testers you only need email addresses, no UDID's, no iTunes, all OTA distribution, it's easy.

Comment: The problem I see with TestFlight is that Apple needs to approve each build first. That means I have to appease the gatekeeper AND I have to wait for them to get around to me. When I send direct IPA's, I don't have to deal with either of those complications.

Comment: For internal testers (25 testers) builds don't need to be approved.  External does.  I have external builds approved between 4hr - 24hr usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update Itunes and i've the same problem. I find another solution to get the iPA :

1. Connect your iPhone and build your project into your device like you do before
2. In the build/iphone folder on your project, open the [App name].xcodeproj
   file, that's open XCode
3. From XCode, in the target build, choose Generic iOS Device then clic on Product menu then Archive
4. After the compilation, the window Organizer will open (the same window you use to send your app to ItunesConnect
5. From the Organizer Window, select your App, then click on the Export... button. Select the option : Save for Developpement Deployment, click on the Next Button, select Export one app for all compatible devices, this will export the iPA on the folder you choose !

Comment: Yes!!! This is the answer. Just to be 100% clear, most people will benefit probably benefit more from the TestFlight answer which is also on this page. If my dev cycle were slower on this project, TestFlight would probably be the best answer. For my particular scenario though, in this particular case, this is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should really look into using Apple's Test Flight. For internal testers you only need email addresses, no UDID's, no iTunes, all OTA distribution, it's easy.

For internal testers (25 testers) builds don't need to be approved. External does. I have external builds approved between 4hr - 24hr usually.

[Official docs on beta testing via TestFlight](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devdc42b26b8)

Comment: So far it's been well over 24hrs. Still no approval, or any other communication from apple. Can't add clients to the connect account, because that gives them too much access. So I'm at Apple's mercy now, where I wasn't before. I can see this being great if things aren't time sensitive. :(

Comment: You can add members without giving them access to your apps data (for use by marketing / legal people)

Comment: Don't add 'users'. Add 'testers'.

Comment: Since builds need to be approved for testers, this is a great solution if time isn't an issue. If one doesn't need to rapid fire builds, this is a great solution. If there are no other solutions then I guess I'll live with it.

Comment: They don’t need to be approved for 25 internal testers.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did for the problem:

1. delete the new iTune.
2. download old version of itune and install it to the mac.
3. gen the ipa like the good old day.
4. use diawi service to send the ipad out!

DONE!

Aaron

Comment: Been looking for the old version to try this. Can't find a reputable source.

Comment: Also, Apple specifically told me that I can't delete iTunes since it's a core app. They also said the os wouldn't allow an older version to be installed over a newer one.

Comment: Oh. I have only heard iTunes not Itune or itune. I have also never heard mac, gen and ipa.

Comment: You can download old version of iTune from Apple: https://support.apple.com/en_SA/downloads/itunes

Comment: Here one of the link about how to delete iTune from the Mac: https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/uninstall-itunes/